# How to solve wordpress theme issue as it goes blank again and again?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress website. When i try to access my website after couple of days it goes blank. Then i reupload my theme, it starts working again. After few days it goes blank again. What is this issue with theme. I am using clementina wordpress theme. Can anyone help with this.

Comment: which server u using?

Comment: For hosting i am using 123-reg.co.uk